# Using system() cross platform. Compiling with cygwin and g++

Tags: c++, cygwin, cross-platform

I'm using cygwin and g++ under Windows 7 to compile my project. I've made a makefile to compile the project under Ubuntu. This is all working so far.

A function calls the Libre Office to convert some files. For this purpose i pass a command string to `system()`.

**Symptom**

When I use the executable generated with cygwin a error occurs:

```
sh: C:\..\LibreOffice 3.6\program\soffice --headless --convert-to png:'draw_png_Export' add1.fodg : command not found
```

What irritates me is the fact, that it seems the command is passed to `sh` and not `cmd`

How can I make sure the executable build for Windows uses no `sh`?

Comment: cygwin is hmmm cygwin. For windows ports you might try MinGw.

Comment: The whole point of Cygwin is to behave *as if* you were on a *nix system. As such, yes, `system()` will call `sh`. If you want to call `cmd`, include it in your command line. You might also want to use [cygpath](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath) to convert between Cygwin and Windows paths.

Comment: @g-makulik With MinGW it's working flawlessly, but every PC in the lab has cygwin installed (as part of a other software installation). So we would like to use that instead of adding another component.

Comment: IIRC MinGW is a single DLL that weights about 1Mb. If it's working flawlessly under MinGW why bother?

Comment: @syam As stated to my previous comment we "only" want to use cygwin because it's already there. I'm not sure if I understand your _include it in your command line_. What do you mean by that? I already differentiate if the project is build under Unix or Windows to use different source files. Would it be possible to specify `cmd` instead of `sh`?

Comment: @WeaslB No, you can't avoid `sh` because that's the shell interpreter under *nix systems (which Cygwin emulates), just like `cmd` is Windows'. However you can have `sh` call something like `cmd "C:\...\program"` (you'll probably need to pass additional options to `cmd`, see its documentation).

Comment: @WeaslB: Even better, link your code statically, and you won't need any dlls :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options.

First, stick with `sh` used by `system()` and use the path to LibreOffice in POSIX format.

```
C:\..\LibreOffice 3.6\program\soffice
```

will become

```
/cygdrive/c/../LibreOffice 3.6/program/soffice
```

You can also use the `cygpath` utility for this, as well.

The other option is to call LibreOffice via cmd:

```
cmd /c C:\..\LibreOffice 3.6\program\soffice args...
```